# How do I rename namespaces in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to consume a Web Service in C# and once I onsume I need to use it in current application.

But, the namespace declarations goes like this:

using File_Attachment_Import_Export.Source_Instance;
Syntax: .

I was wondering if there was a way where I could rename it like this:
using File_Attachment_Import_Export.Source_Instance as Source;

This renaming capability(if exist) it would help me great deal!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to somewhere in your project where the namespace is declared, if you drag your mouse over the namespace and press `F2`, changing the namespace should replace it everywhere it exists in your project! 
That's what I have used in Visual Studio at least.